# awk, from last column to \r\n (CRNL)

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a file with lines like so:

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.0.29 (192.168.0.29), Dst: www.l.google.com (64.233.187.104)
    Time to live: 128
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0\r\n
```

if I use $NF I end up with:

```
rv:1.7.5)
```

but I want:

```
Firefox/1.0
```

I want to make my script, below, do that:

```
awk '
    /    User-Agent/{brow=$NF}
    END{
        print brow;
    }
'
```

any suggestions would be appreciated!

Full script: (fixed)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1;
awk '/    User-Agent/{print}' $1 > useragents_$1;
echo '----------------------------------------------------' >> useragents_$1;
sort useragents_$1 | uniq >> useragents_$1;
awk '
    /Internet Protocol Version 4, Src:/{ip=$(NF-4)}
    /    Time to live/{ttl++}
    /    Time to live/{sttl=$NF}
    /    User-Agent/{os=$(NF-6)" "$(NF-5)}
    /    User-Agent/{brow=$NF}
    /    User-Agent/{agent++}
    /    User-Agent/{stringtemp=sttl"\t"ip"\t"os"\t"brow}
    /Windows/{windows++}
    /Linux/{linux++}
    /Solaris/{solaris++}
    END{
        sub(/\\r.*$/, "", brow);
        print "TTL\tIP\t\tOS\t\tBROWSER";
        print stringtemp;
        print "\nSUMMARY";
        print "\tttl\t=\t"ttl; print "\twindows\t=\t"windows;
        print "\tlinux\t=\t"linux; print "\tsolaris\t=\t"solaris;
        print "\tagent\t=\t"agent
    }
' $1 > useragents_$1;
more useragents_$1;
```

Output:

```
examplehttppacket.txt
TTL     IP              OS              BROWSER
128     192.168.0.29    Windows NT      Firefox/1.0\r\n

SUMMARY
        ttl     =       1
        windows =       3
        linux   =
        solaris =
        agent   =       1
```

Thanks for all your help everybody, looks like it was mostly a text file problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk should work:

```
awk '/User-Agent/{brow=$NF} END{sub(/\\r.*$/, "", brow); print brow;}' file
```

Comment: I didn't get it to work, perhaps with a one liner, I updated above.

Comment: Input data in your question, are these 3 different lines? Can you show be output of `cat http_packet.txt | od -bc`

Comment: added above at bottom of problem

Comment: sorry shift those right one column, didn't paste all that well (fixed)

Comment: same output, unfortunately. Code above updated to show what I changed

Comment: Okay, it appears something strange was going on with my file so I uploaded it again and now it's working great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that your sample script has a typo (i.e., that you mean `/User-Agent/`, with no leading spaces), then given this input file:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0
```

And this script:

```
awk '
    /User-Agent/{brow=$NF}
    END{
        print brow;
    }
'
```

Then I get this output:

```
Firefox/1.0
```

Which seems to be exactly what you want.  If you're seeing different behavior, please update your question with information about your operating system and an example of actual input and actual output that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/User-Agent/{brow=$NF}; END{print brow;}' file_name
```

Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the first thing to try is to remove the `\r` chars

```
awk '
    {gsub(/^M/, "", $0)}
    /    User-Agent/{brow=$NF}
    END{
        print brow;
    } file
```

If using the VI(M) editor, enter the Ctrl-M (^M above) as one char, and using `vi(m)`s escape char feature, by pressing Ctrl-V (and then) Ctrl-M.

IHTH

Comment: I tried that (see above) but it gave me the same thing. Cool idea.